# How to refresh the page on form submit button click and then show the results in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I know this is a simple question, but I researched online and tried out many things but it didn't work out.

I am making a simple file transfer time estimator, and all I need is the page to reload and then show the results when the calculate button is clicked. (similar to how it would have worked if it was made in PHP.)

I either get stuck in a reload loop or I lose form data when I try to do this.  I am adding the variables to the URL when the submit button is clicked, and I want the user to go to this page(with a refresh) and the results scroll into view.

Here is the relevant HTML

```
        <div class="content"> 



<form onsubmit="return false">
<div id="speed">
    <h3>How fast is your transfer speed?</h3>


    <p>
        <label for="internetSpeed">File Transfer Speed</label>
        <input id="internetSpeed_p" type="button" value="+" onclick="internetSpeed.value = (parseInt(internetSpeed.value)+1).toFixed(2)">
        <input id="internetSpeed" type="number" min="0" step="0.01" value="10" placeholder="File Transfer speed" autofocus>


        <input id="internetSpeed_p" type="button" value="-" onclick="internetSpeed.value = (parseInt(internetSpeed.value)-1).toFixed(2)">

        <select id="internetSpeedBase">
            <option value="10^3">Kbps</option>
            <option value="10^6" selected>Mbps</option>
            <option value="10^9">Gbps</option>

        </select>
    </p>


    <div>
        <label class="collapse" for="_1">?</label>
        <input id="_1" type="checkbox">
        <div>
            <p class="overhead-p"><label for="internetOverhead">Overhead</label>
                <select id="internetOverhead">
                    <option value="1" selected>None</option>
                    <option value="0.99">1%</option>
                    <option value="0.95">5%</option>
                    <option value="0.9">10% (Typical TCP overhead)</option>
                    <option value="0.85">15%</option>
                    <option value="0.8">20%</option>
                    <option value="0.75">25%</option>
                    <option value="0.7">30%</option>
                    <option value="0.6">40%</option>
                    <option value="0.5">50%</option>
                    <option value="0.4">60%</option>
                    <option value="0.3">70%</option>
                    <option value="0.2">80%</option>
                    <option value="0.1">90%</option>
                    <option value="0.05">95%</option>
                    <option value="0.01">99%</option>
                </select>

            </p>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

<div id="file">
    <h3>What is the size of the file you want to transfer?</h3>
    <p> 
        <label for="fileSize">File Size</label>
        <input id="internetSpeed_p" type="button" value="+" onclick="fileSize.value = (parseInt(fileSize.value)+1).toFixed(2)">

        <input type="number" id="fileSize" value="1" step="0.01" min="0">

        <input id="internetSpeed_p" type="button" value="-" onclick="fileSize.value = (parseInt(fileSize.value)-1).toFixed(2)">
        <select id="fileSizeBase">
            <option value="2^10">KB </option>
            <option value="2^20">MB </option>
            <option value="2^30" selected>GB </option>
            <option value="2^40">TB </option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p>
        <button id="calculateButton"  >Calculate</button>
    </p>
</div>

</form>

<div id="results">
    <div id="results_inner">                
        <p class="">It would take</p>
        <p class="time">0</p>
        <p class="">to transfer <span class="size"></span> </p>
        <p class="">at <span class="speed"></span>/sec</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

And, here is the javascript

```
window.onload=function(){

calculateButton.onclick = calc;


if(window.location.hash){
    var uri = window.location.hash;
    internetSpeed.value = uri.match(/speed=([\d.]+)x(\d+\^\d+)/)[1];
    internetSpeedBase.value = uri.match(/speed=([\d.]+)x(\d+\^\d+)/)[2];
    internetOverhead.value = uri.match(/overhead=([\d.]+)/)[1];

    fileSize.value = uri.match(/file=([\d.]+)x(\d+\^\d+)/)[1];
    fileSizeBase.value = uri.match(/file=([\d.]+)x(\d+\^\d+)/)[2];

    calc();
}
else if(window.localStorage){
    if(window.localStorage.getItem('downloadtime.speed')){
        internetSpeed.value = window.localStorage.getItem('downloadtime.speed');
        internetSpeedBase.value = window.localStorage.getItem('downloadtime.speedBase');
        internetOverhead.value = window.localStorage.getItem('downloadtime.overhead');
        fileSize.value = window.localStorage.getItem('downloadtime.file');
        fileSizeBase.value = window.localStorage.getItem('downloadtime.fileBase');
    }
    else defaults();
}
else defaults();


};

function defaults(){
internetSpeed.value = "10";
internetSpeedBase.value = "10^6";
internetOverhead.value = "0.9";
fileSize.value = "1";
fileSizeBase.value = "2^30";
}

function calc(){

// Internet speed

var internet = {
    speed: internetSpeed.value,
    factor: internetSpeedBase.value,
    overhead: internetOverhead.value,
}

internet.speed = parseFloat(internet.speed);
internet.overhead = parseFloat(internet.overhead);
internet.factor = {
    base: internet.factor.match(/(\d+)\^(\d+)/)[1],
    power: internet.factor.match(/(\d+)\^(\d+)/)[2]
}

internet.bitsPerSec = internet.speed * Math.pow(internet.factor.base, internet.factor.power);
internet.bytesPerSec = internet.bitsPerSec/8;

//File size

var file = {
    size: fileSize.value,
    factor: fileSizeBase.value,
}

file.size = parseFloat(file.size);
file.factor = {
    base: file.factor.match(/(\d+)\^(\d+)/)[1],
    power: file.factor.match(/(\d+)\^(\d+)/)[2]
}
file.bytes = file.size * Math.pow(file.factor.base, file.factor.power);

//speed
internet.effectiveBytesPerSec = internet.bytesPerSec * internet.overhead;

//download time in milliseconds
var transferTime_ms = (file.bytes/internet.effectiveBytesPerSec)*1000;


if(window.location){
    var uri=[];
    uri.push("file="+fileSize.value+"x"+fileSizeBase.value);
    uri.push("speed="+internetSpeed.value+"x"+internetSpeedBase.value);
    uri.push("overhead="+internetOverhead.value);
    window.location.hash = uri.join("&");
}

if(window.localStorage){        
    window.localStorage.setItem('downloadtime.speed', internetSpeed.value);
    window.localStorage.setItem('downloadtime.speedBase', internetSpeedBase.value);
    window.localStorage.setItem('downloadtime.overhead', internetOverhead.value);
    window.localStorage.setItem('downloadtime.file', fileSize.value);
    window.localStorage.setItem('downloadtime.fileBase', fileSizeBase.value);
}


//Show results
document.querySelector("#results .time").innerHTML = moment.preciseDiff(0, transferTime_ms);
document.querySelector("#results .size").innerHTML = prefixByteLong(file.bytes);
document.querySelector("#results .speed").innerHTML = prefixByte(internet.effectiveBytesPerSec);

document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = "visible";

document.getElementById("results").scrollIntoView();

}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please search for PHP AJAX

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for the comment, but I am not trying to do it in PHP 
 AJAX. And, If I am right, I want quite the opposite of what AJAX does. I want the page to refresh and then show the results.

Comment: use jquery `$(document).ready(function(){
    //your function or code
});`.whenever the page refresh document ready function will trigger

Comment: If you've got no server-side involved, you need another way to persist the results (because pages are inherently stateless by default). Have you look ed at using something like localstorage? Or, even better, ditch the page reloading and just manipulate all the content using Javascript to show/hide/add/remove relevant elements.

Comment: Please click the `<>` button, include all relevant code (moment and preciseDiff), comment out the localStorage stuff since it does not work here - then you have a [mcve] - then tell us what you need the script to achieve, not what you think you need to do (X/Y problem)